# If my database has to stay in one region, is there much point distributing my API across several?

Tags: database, latency

We currently have an API and database in Australia, and are attempting to reduce latency in other countries.

Coming to grips with the CAP theorem for synchronized databases is probably a little out-of-scope at present, but we're looking into horizontal scaling across several regions (e.g, have servers in US/EU/Asia).

Now, where I'm scratching my head is, would this approach yield any latency benefit? There's obvious benefits in having a server nearer to the user, but in exchange, the database (being still in Australia) is now far further away.

I hope this all makes sense, I'm pretty new to devOps kinda stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on your use case. For example, often the distribution of database writes vs database reads is sharper than 1:10. Also the API endpoints for reading are often used more than for create/update/delete operations. In this case, you can implement local caching for certain queries to decrease the response time.

Also, it's quite easy to set up multi-region read replicas for your database. This is supported by many hosted databases (MongoDB Atlas, Amazon RDS, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I believe some context is missing from the question.

I assume that you mean that you would like to set up API servers in the (US/EU/Asia).

This very much depends on what the API is actually is doing.

If you can cache at the API server, then you can get a much better latency.